# Sqlalchemy FIlter based on subtype

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using a join-based inheritance - I have `User`(parent) and `CorporateUser`(child) models.  The polymorphic_identity of User is `"user"` and the one of the CorporateUser is `"corporate_user"`.
I have a query like this
`User.query.filter(User.name.like("%"+search_text+"%"))`
Is it possible to "chain" to this query something that will only return objects of type `CorporateUser`?
Currently I just add another `User.query.filter(User.name.like("%"+search_text+"%")).filter(User.type == 'corporate_user')`
but this doesn't seem very elegant.

I am aware I can just do `CorporateUser.query.filter(User.name.like("%"+search_text+"%"))`
but the point is that I am given the filters of the initial query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `.with_entities()` can help you. It will not exactly return the `CorporateUser`, but only the fields you defined.

```
query = User.query.filter(User.name.like("%"+search_text+"%")) \
    .filter(User.type == 'corporate_user') \
    .with_entities(User.corporate_user)
```

Each item in your query result will be a tuple with the entities defined.

Of course, your model need the `User.corporate_user` back reference. Based on your question, I'm not sure if you have it.

Comment: Just seeing this now - apologies. I ended up having a "base" GenericUser and two subclasses - NormalUser and CorporateUser - querying now is much simpler. 
Also, the approach I took is to put a .join(CorporateCustomer) after the .filter - so that the name filter is applied and then just the CorporateCustomers are returned.